# Google Street View problem - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am having a problem with google street view. Basically, the street view is to be placed inside a hidden div. The div will be revealed when clicking on a button.

The street view loads fine the first time, but if I hide the div and then show it again, the street view window just shows a gray background.

You can check it out here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrrT/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will fix it

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#sv').toggle();
    google.maps.event.trigger(sv, 'resize')
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrrT/3/)